# Creating an efficent and time-saving algorithm to find difference between greater than and lesser than combination

Tags: python, list, algorithm, sorting

I want to create a python script, where I have a list of 14 digits and have to find the integer formed by a specific combination of all digits, with the requirement that the number of such combinations that are smaller than this integer exceeds the number of combinations that are greater than the integer by 5617961. [image: My algorithm right now.] This is what i've come up with. It should work but the obvious negative side is it's slow and inefficent. So I need help with coming up with a better algorithm.
Also my code:

```
from itertools import permutations

def generate_combinations(lst, length):
    for combo in permutations(lst, length):
        yield ''.join(map(str, combo))

# List setup
lst = [2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8]
length = 14
FiveLst = []


for combination in generate_combinations(lst, length):
    arv = [int(x) for x in str(combination)]
    if arv[0] == 5 and arv[1] == 8:
        print(combination)
        FiveLst.append(combination)
for Fiveno in FiveLst:
    difmin = 0
    difplus = 0
    for combination in generate_combinations(lst, length):
        if combination > Fiveno:
            difplus += 1
        else:
            difmin += 1
    difference = difmin-difplus
    if difference == 5617961:
        print(f"Combination found!: {combination}")
        break

print("Process complete!")
exit()
```

Comment: have to be the elements of the list single-digit numbers? How is comparison between combinations defined?

Comment: you could `list.remove` a `5` and a `8` from the original list (or a copy of it) and permute the resulting list with `n-2` elements

Comment: I think the main part could look like this`for c1, c2 in combinations(permutations(smaller_lst, len(smaller_lst)), 2):
    out = do_comparison(c1, c2)
    check_break(out)` + for the `out` one should take care again of the `58` part

Comment: `difference == 5617961` will never be true, so you might as well just do `print("Process complete!")` to achieve the same output.

Comment: @no comment `14!` is `87178291200` so it is possible

Comment: @cards How do you get an odd difference with an even number of combinations?

Comment: @no comment that's a good point! Could it be that _"are 5617961 more than combinations"_ should be translate to `difference > 5617961`?

Comment: @cards Nah they just need to count correctly.

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding (because the formulation of the problem seems close to gibberish to me...). Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you mean: "Find the combination (of the 14 digits),  such that the difference between the NUMBER of combinations smaller than it and the NUMBER of combinations greater than it is 5617961 " .

Comment: If I interpreted your question correctly, we know the total number of combinations of those 14 digits is 14! / (4! 2! 3! 2! 3!) = 25 225 200 ; so the number you seek if the (25 225 200 + 1 + 5 617 961)th = 15 421 581 th combination (in ascending order). You only have to devise a way to find this one.

Comment: @nocomment: with an even total number of combinations, the difference between the number of combinations lower than a given combo x and the number of combos greater than x will ALWAYS be odd; don't forget x itself!

Comment: @Swifty I don't. The OP does.

Comment: Oh you mean the code. I hadn't looked at it yet (was busy trying to decypher the question itself :) ). Indeed that `else` will make the algorithm fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it's actually a fun problem, I wrote an algorithm that doesn't rely on building then counting permutations, but rather on mathematically calculating them;
the `count_permutations_beginning_with` function literally does what its name says, and the `build_x` function recursively builds the rank-th combination.

```
from collections import Counter

lst = [2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8]
expected_diff = 5_617_961

initial_digits = Counter(str(d) for d in sorted(lst))


def fac(n):
    return n * fac(n-1) if n else 1


def count_permutations_beginning_with(n):
    digits = initial_digits.copy()
    digits.subtract(n)
    prod = 1
    for c in digits.values():
        prod *= fac(c)
    return fac(digits.total()) // prod


def build_x(rank, root='', remaining_digits=None):
    if remaining_digits is None:
        remaining_digits = initial_digits.copy()
    print (rank, root, remaining_digits)
    if not remaining_digits.total():
        return root
    for d in remaining_digits:
        if not remaining_digits[d]:
            continue
        if (d_quantity := count_permutations_beginning_with(root + d)) < rank:
            rank -= d_quantity
        else:
            break
    remaining_digits.subtract(d)
    return build_x(rank, root + d, remaining_digits)


x_rank = (count_permutations_beginning_with('') + 1 + expected_diff) // 2

print(build_x(x_rank))
# '58225522644668'
```